# Does anyone know how to stop Firefox from adding shortcuts for every single website I visit?

Tags: firefox

I want to try and have a kind of different Firefox shortcut layout because I think all of it being filled up is boring.

And now, every time I open any site that isn't the ones already in there, it gets added to the shortcuts, and I have to go through the arduous process to dismiss everyone of them and sometimes they overlap so I have to do it like 40 times.

So, I have look through the entire internet and can't find a way to stop Firefox from adding that, is there even a way to do that?

Even if it's through using JavaScript code or something I just want a solution.

[image: image:]

Comment: If it is every single site you have visited, that is browsing history and not shortcuts. Perhaps you have to change the setting for what to show in a new browser tab/window to “blank?”

Comment: Where do you see this list (new tab or other)?